# How to Get All Memory Path (Internal or External Memory) list in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm facing problem to detect all memory path in Android device.
If we try with provide tips and example we aren't able to getting proper external memory path.

For Example :

If we try to get external memory in Samsung Tab 2
Used code ::

> **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()**

It will provide us internal Mounted Memory path.
//storage/sdcard0/

After lot of googling i found one application which show all path of device

Application Name "**ES Explorer**"
This application showing all path of Memory.

Please provide us any solution so we can fix our problem

Comment: "it we provide us internal Mounted Memory path" -- that is external storage. You may wish to read the documentation on external storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 1):

Beyond those types of storage volumes specifically supported by the standard Android SDK is a wide variety of vendor- and version- unique possibilities.

You can find all mounted filesystems by reading `/proc/mounts` as a text file.

However:

- This will only find filesystems which are actually mounted - for example, it will not find USB storage volumes if they are handled as arbitrary USB accessories by an application, rather than mounted by the Linux operating system underlying Android.
- You will have to apply some logic to filter out all the other various file systems which are not general storage devices and show up in the list.  It used to be that you could detect "external" storage volumes by looking for `"vfat"` as a type, but that is no longer used in recent Android versions
- Especially in recent Android versions, the actual path of the mount as discovered from `/proc/mounts` and the path customarily used may not match, as the customary path may redirect to the actual one by multiple levels of symbolic links

Answer (score 0):

Samsung handles their storage a little differently than some other devices unfortunately. Ever since their version of Android 3.2, they have also disallowed the writing to the external storage by regular apps. That being said, you can still read(access) the external storages. Below are the paths to the two possible external storage locations. I actually have programmed specifically for the Galaxy Tab 2.0 (7 inch), so here ya go:

Inserted microSD card: `mnt/extSdCard`
Connected external storage via Samsung USB Adapter: `mnt/UsbDriveA` 
"sdcard" storage(not an inserted SD card): `getExternalStorageDirectory()` as you know.

I've tried multiple ways to use functions to find the path, but haven't had any luck ever. However, this works, so I'm content. I hope it can help you too.

Comment: Hi Steven ,As per you comment this thing working fine only in Samsung device but when we try to found the external memory path in different device then its not working fine...is there any other solution for find the path

Comment: Here lies the problem with manufacturers and their version of Android.. Android only knows what the MANUFACTURERS label as the "External Storage Directory." if `getExternalStorageDirectory()` leads to an internal storage location, then you won't have a systemic way of looking for it.
What you'll have to do instead is predefine different path ways. 
If you've ever done any web programming, you can see the same case be done depending on what browser the client is running. You may make/get an object differently if a person is running IE versus Firefox.
It's a pain, but it must be done for now.

Comment: There's a bit of a terminology problem here.  getExternalStorageDirectory() is required to point to something which is usable for the purpose Android defines for external storage, regardless of where it is physically implemented (removable, soldered down, etc).  Anything else is beyond the requirements of Android and vendor unique.  "Internal Storage" on the other hand refers to the potentially app-private folders traditionally located on the /data partition.

Comment: @ChrisStratton,
You are correct. It is Samsung unique. I only worded it that way to separate it from the external storage microSD slot, as well as the external storage option via the Samsung Adapter + USB storage drive.
I will, however, rephrase it now.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
public static File FileCache(Context context) {
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    File cacheDir;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "TechTool_Pdf");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    return cacheDir;
}
```

Comment: Provide code is not working for external memory path(SD Card) .Its provide the path of External phone memory path .Which we can get using this code::getExternalStorageDirectory()